# Animation not showing up in Compositor

Tags: animation, movie-clip-editor, compositing-nodes

pretty new to blender. Following a tutorial from 2017 on how to create laser eyes over a video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCc51vABR94 I can't seem to get my view layer to show up in my compositing window. I also can't get any of it to show up when I render it.
Here is my .blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iNxpDJ9b61QGamAHmqkBjI5jjlrQqzc5/view?usp=sharing
sorry if this a stupid question, thanks for any help

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to:

- Disable *Output > Post-Processing > Sequencer*, otherwise the movie that is loaded into the video sequencer will render, not your current scene.
- In the *Compositor*, plug your *Render Layers* node (or whatever comes after) into an *(Output) Composite* node, otherwise nothing will be rendered.